# What is a tGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

We are starting to use the Telerik MVC controls and had a question about the jquery used. What is a tGrid from the following example and could someone point to more information?

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("tGrid");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The client side grid object is stored in a data store. So if we want to use that client object and the object model (e.g. events, methods etc) we first have to get that object.

[ClientSideObject](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#ClientSideObject)

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking for any information about `.data("tGrid")`:

It's from Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC and if you use [Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/migration/migrating-from-telerik-extensions-for-aspnet-mvc#client-side-object-retrieval) (you use *Kendo.Mvc.UI* namespace) you should use

```
$("#foo").data("kendoGrid")
```

Which gives you [kendo.ui.Grid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#kendouigrid)